# Can't xpath field inside one2many_list widget

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-9

I try to xpath the field partner_id which is inside of an one2many_list widget. Somehow noone of the paths i tried causes any changes.

```py
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(AccountMove, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    for node in doc.xpath("//page//field//tree//field[@name='partner_id']"):
        if not self._is_group_8():
            node.set('options', "{'no_open': True ,'no_create_edit': True}")
    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

Thats the whole view which contains the mentioned field.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form string="Account Entry">
    <header>
        <button name="post" states="draft" string="Post" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="account.group_account_invoice"/>
        <button name="131" states="posted" string="Reverse Entry" type="action" groups="account.group_account_invoice"/>
        <button name="button_cancel" states="posted" string="Cancel Entry" type="object" groups="account.group_account_invoice"/>
        <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
    </header>
    <sheet>
        <div class="oe_button_box">
            <button name="open_reconcile_view" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-bars" type="object" string="View reconciled entries">
            </button>
        </div>
        <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only" attrs="{'invisible':[('name','=','/')]}"/>
        <h1>
            <field name="name" readonly="True" attrs="{'invisible':[('name','=','/')]}"/>
        </h1>
        <group>
            <group>
                <field name="journal_id" options="{'no_open': True, 'no_create': True}"/>
                <field name="company_id" required="1" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                <field name="partner_id" domain="['|',('parent_id', '=', False), ('is_company', '=', True)]"/>
            </group>
            <group>
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="ref"/>
                <field name="amount" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
            </group>
        </group>
        <notebook>
            <page string="Journal Items">
                <field name="line_ids" widget="one2many_list" context="{'line_ids': line_ids, 'journal_id': journal_id }">
                    <tree editable="bottom" string="Journal Items">
        This one -->    <field name="partner_id" domain="['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('is_company', '=', True)]"/>
                        <field name="account_id" domain="[('company_id', '=', parent.company_id), ('deprecated', '=', False)]"/>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="analytic_account_id" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting" domain="[('account_type', '=', 'normal')]"/>
                        <field name="amount_currency" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>
                        <field name="company_currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="currency_id" options="{'no_create': True}" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>
                        <field name="debit" sum="Total Debit"/>
                        <field name="credit" sum="Total Credit"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <field name="narration" colspan="4" placeholder="Add an internal note..." nolabel="1" height="50"/>
            </page>
         </notebook>
    </sheet>
</form>
```

The python code itself is working, cause i am using the same for other fields.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

EDIT: Its possible to modify the field with the xpath method in xml file like this:

```
<xpath expr="//page/field[1]/tree/field[@name='partner_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="partner_id" options="{'no_open': True ,'no_create_edit': True}" domain="['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('is_company', '=', True)]"/>
            </xpath>
```

But this path is not working in my python method, the field does not change.

Does anyone know how to get this done with python?

Comment: could it be `&debug` and `&action` that is causing the problem? placing them inside the attribute would make the XML malformed.

Comment: No thats my fault. This is not contained in the view, somehow i failed the copy paste to stackoverflow, its fixed now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Between `page` and `field` there should be only one slash:

```xml
//page/field[1]/tree/field[@name='partner_id']
```

Anyway if some xpath is not working try being as much clear as possible, try this expression as well:

```xml
/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='line_ids']/tree/field[@name='partner_id']
```

Comment: Both not working. I guess this is caused by the one2many_list widget, seems like i can not reach the fields inside of the widget with the usual xpath methods.

Comment: Your first path is working if i use the xpath method in xml file but not with the python method which im also using for other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with this xpath...

```
<xpath expr="//form//sheet//notebook//page//field[@name='line_ids']//
    tree//field[@name='partner_id']" position="replace"/>
```